# What's wrong with my bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, fedora

I am having difficulties figuring out what is wrong with my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Good Day $USER"

if [ -f "$1" ]
then 
    tar -cvf home-10-07-2017.tar --files-from /dev/null
    echo "You are about to back up the following files… $*"
for i in "$@"
do
    if [ -f "$i" ]
    then
        PROCEED='YES'
    else
         PROCEED='NO'
    fi  

    if [ $PROCEED='YES' ]
    then
        tar -rvf home-10-07-2017.tar "$i"
    fi
done
        tar -vzf home-10-07-2017.tar.gz
else
      echo 'You did not enter any files to backup'
fi
```

When I run script I get the following error

```
./backups.sh first.txt second.txt 
Good Day fed
You are about to back up the following files… first.txt second.txt
first.txt
second.txt
tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label'      options
```

Comment: `[` is a **command,** not a special token.  It needs space before and after.

Comment: Also see list of "shell scripting basics" questions on my profile page; there are other common mistakes present such as unquoted variables and unquoted `$@`.

Comment: Have you tried [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Please clean your code with the help of that site.

Comment: A `for i in $@` needs to be in quotes: `for i in "$@"` to work correctly. The `$i` should also be quoted "$i"

Comment: If the help from shellcheck is not enough, please change the question to the one you actually have.

Comment: @Arrow, or just `for i do`

Comment: @ Arrow I updated the code using spellcheck, thanks for the help!

Comment: `tar -vzf` lacks one of `-Acdtrux` so probably instead should be `tar -tvzf ...` to list the contents, assuming that's what that line is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual error from `tar` on the last line (which I guess was your primary question) is because you haven't specified an actual action. The `f` specifies that a filename follows. The `v` says to do something verbosely. The `z` says the file is compressed (and with most versions of `tar` is redundant).

I guess the action you wanted was `t` - to list the files. In which case, you'd need:

```
tar -tvzf home-10-07-2017.tar.gz
```